# AppBarButton.Flyout bad positioning

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

A have the following CommandBar in my Windows Phone 8.1 (I'm using the Universal template):

```
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Label="add task" Click="GoToAddTask">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Label="sort by">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Sort" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{Binding SortByDate}" Text="Date" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Priority" Command="{Binding SortByPriority}" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Name" Command="{Binding SortByName}" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Label="pin project" Command="{Binding PinProject}">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Pin" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

The problem is that when the user click the `AppBarButton` "sort by", the Flyout's bottom edge seems to be stuck to the bottom of the screen behind the AppBar itself. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Flyout positioning]

I checked the Windows 8.1 equivalent and it works fine (as illustrated for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20336518/404764)).

I assumes that the Flyout would be shown above the AppBar itself.

Comment: Have you verified this is also the case on a phone?

Comment: Yes, same thing on a physical device.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if `AppBarButton.Flyout` were meant to be supported in this release. I suggest you raise the issue on Microsoft Connect, and not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It appears it's meant to be supported. [This MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465341.aspx) has a discussion on drop-down menus talking about this very use of it.

Comment: By the way if you want the real standard ( like the mail app ) and have the flyout at the base of the screen above the appbar take a look at Tim's solution! http://timgabrhel.com/blog/flyout-on-windows-phone-8-1-runtime/

Comment: This one was irritating, confirmed on a Lumia 1520. Strange thing is it worked for only one flyout added. When more flyouts were added for other AppBarButtons placement went crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue.  Instead of putting the MenuFlyout in-line, create it on the click event:

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuFlyout mf = (MenuFlyout)this.Resources["MyFlyout"];

            mf.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;
            mf.ShowAt(this.root);
        }
```

See if that works.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I hope this issue gets fixed, it seems like a basic use case.

Comment: In case anyone else gets stuck trying to figure out what "this.root" is pointing at, it needs to be the CommandBar element defined in the XAML, e.g. <CommandBar x:Name="root">

Comment: for me it works in all the emulators but on Lumia 735, the same problem persists.

Comment: This worked great though if I called mf.ShowAt(CommandBar) or even the AppBarButton then it would not work.  I needed to call ShowAt on an element of the page and then it would fit above the CommandBar perfectly.

Comment: I can confirm I have a user with a Lumia 735 and the problem persists, just like for @IgorKulman.