# Show flyout using BottomAppBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to show a simple Flyout (with informational content) when a AppBarToggleButton within BottomAppBar is pressed, but my solution doesn't work. :(

This is my code:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarToggleButton x:Uid="MapPageAppBarLegend" Label="" Icon="List">
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <Flyout>
                        <TextBlock Text="Informations here..."/>
                    </Flyout>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            </AppBarToggleButton>
        </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Nothing appears.. Can anyone help me to showing this flayout? 
Thank you very much and sorry for my english language. :)

Pame

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23326717/2681948) will help you.

Comment: @Romasz Thank you but I will show the flayout on AppBarToggleButton click and not in a AppBarButton.. and I cannot use the same way used for AppBarButton.. I don't know why, there are both button at the end..

Comment: Thought, I haven't played with this much, I guess that one solution if there aren't others provided, may be [the answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23523126/2681948) - show Flyout upon your Button event. Have you tried like this?

Comment: Seems strange you want to use a toggle button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything is quite clearly described [at  MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx) (there is also a very good example there):

Nothing appears, because *Flyouts* open automatically only for buttons (and [AppBarToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbartogglebutton) doesn't derive from `Button` class):

> A flyout attached to a button opens automatically when the user clicks the button. You don't need to handle any events to open the flyout. (This includes controls derived from Button, like AppBarButton

Of course you can add a `Flyout` to any `FrameworkElement` but you will have to open it manually:

> You can attach a Flyout control to any FrameworkElement object by using the FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout attached property. If you do so, you must respond to an interaction on the FrameworkElement, such as the Tapped event, and open the Flyout in your code.

In XAML - define your `Flyout` in Resources and attach it to button:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Key="myFlyout" Placement="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Informations here..."/>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarToggleButton x:Uid="MapPageAppBarLegend" Label="First" Icon="List"
                            FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource myFlyout}"
                            Click="AppBarToggleButton_Click"/>                
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

And event in code behind:

```
private void AppBarToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);  
}
```