# Toggle BottomAppBar on opening ContentDialog control in UWP Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

In my UWP application originally developed for Win8.1, I have a Page BottomAppBar control in all pages which holds an Appbar button and a command bar. There is a link in the command bar inside BottomAppBar to open a full sized content dialog screen as shown in the below screenshot. In Windows Phone 8.1 (first screenshot), when opening the content dialog, the bottomappbar is getting hidden automatically. But in Windows Phone 10 (second screenshot), the bottomappbar is not hidden, hiding a few settings at the bottom.

I am not sure how would I be able to control the AppBar on the contentdialog code.

Win8.1:

[image]

Win10:

[image]

Any suggestions would greatly help.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677814/flyout-behind-appbar

Comment: I have tested it on the Emulator and my Windows phone, and I **cannot reproduce this issue**: On Windows Phone 10, when opening the content dialog, the bottomappbar is **also getting hidden automatically**. Could you share your project or some sample code which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I was not sure why it is not replicable on your end. Might be the problem with my app? However, I handled it by using a navigation service, which I am using for navigating between pages. When trying to open the content dialog from a page, I'd hide the bottom app bar. On the content dialog control, I would store the source page and would use it when navigating back to the page adding an additional parameter to the navigation args. On the source page, based on the arg, I'd make the bottom app bar visibile.