# C# WinRT Windows Phone 8.1 - App Bar Covers Flyout Menu When Nav Bar Is Visible

Tags: c#, user-interface, menu, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app that uses a bottom app bar.  The bottom app bar opens a menu flyout when one of the app bar buttons is clicked.  When the flyout menu is opened, the bottom of it is partially covered by the app bar.  This only occurs when the virtual nav bar is visible.  If the virtual nav bar is hidden, or the phone has physical navigation buttons, then the flyout menu displays properly in it's entirety.

I researched this thoroughly and it's not a duplicate.

A similar question is [Flyout behind Appbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677814/flyout-behind-appbar).  I tried hiding the bottom app bar when the flyout menu is shown, but then the flyout menu is just hidden behind the virtual nav bar.

Another similar question is [AppBarButton.Flyout bad positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326717/appbarbutton-flyout-bad-positioning).  I tried creating the flyout menu programmatically, but the flyout menu was still obscured.

I tried creating a new app with only the bottom app bar, an app bar button and a menu flyout, with the same results.  I tested it in the emulator with physical navigation buttons, in the emulator with the virtual nav bar and on my physical device with the virtual nav bar.

Please note that to test this in the emulator with the virtual nav bar buttons you have to set it to the 720P or 1080P emulator and then click Tools, Sensors, enable Software Buttons, click Apply and then wait for the OS to restart.

I tried adding an extra blank menu flyout item at the bottom of the menu flyout to compensate for space at the bottom, but that is not desirable when the virtual nav bar is hidden, because then there is an empty space visible.  The same goes for adding a bottom margin to the last menu flyout item.

I also tried experimenting with ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible and ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow and hiding or showing the bottom app bar without getting any consistent results.

This seems like a bug but there must be a reasonable solution since using the Calendar app and clicking the view button to select day, week, month or year seems to work perfectly regardless of whether the virtual nav bar is visible or hidden or the phone doesn't use the virtual nav bar at all.

I would like to have the menu flyout not covered by the bottom app bar.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try PopUpMenu class?
This class gives u almost the same experience as Flyout Menu does, unless it doesn't pop up the element it's shown on and can be easily shown in any position.
I guess your problem may be solved by using it.

Here's the documentation for it
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208693

Comment: I can't find any documentation for this online.  Could you post a link or reference?