# How do you bind a ListItem to a context menu in a ListView?

Tags: listview, contextmenu, winui-3

I've got a ListView control with several items in it. Some if the items on the list are active, some are not. I want a context menu to pop up when I right click on an item in the list and give me one set of options for the disabled items (e.g. enable) and another set of options for enabled items (e.g. send, cancel, disable).

There is no ItemsSource on any of the menu or context menu items that I've found. How are we supposed to connect a view model to the context menu of an item in a ListBox?

Comment: You may want to check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024942/how-do-you-bind-menuflyout-itemsource-with-collection-when-there-are-multiple

Comment: @Quarkly: Create an attached property or use a `Flyout`.