# Dynamic menu in Universal Application

Tags: uwp, menu, win-universal-app

I would like to create a menu bound to a Collection of a ViewModel. Unfortunately, it seems that the [Menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/menus) controls don't expose an `ItemsSource` property to do so.

Is there any MVVM-friendly way to achieve this?

For those wondering why I want such a thing, it's because my application has plugins, and depending on them, a number of options will be available as menu actions.
Also, for those still wondering, the actions are related to the common "Import" menu in many applications.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336517/why-doesnt-the-windows-8-1-menuflyout-have-itemssource-property) which uses Flyout, via adding an attached property to identify the ItemsSource and the ItemTemplate for a Flyout control to achieve the binding.

When tried to replace the Flyout with MenuFlyout, but since there is no `content` property in Menuflyout, it can't host the created itemcontrol. It seems that Menuflyout is limited, so you could try to use Flyout to achieve.